# How to create a Hyperlink as part of a static text using JasperSoft Studio?

Tags: url, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a StaticText, which has a text like

> If you want to be a member of our website, then make sure you let us
>   know by sending an email to foo@bar.com as soon as possible.

This text is inside the `<![CDATA[...]]` of the text tag. I would like to make sure that foo@bar.com is a clickable email address. I have researched this for a long while and the best I could come up with was to modify it to mailto:foo@bar.com and then it became a clickable link if opened with Chromium (without the blue color, unfortunately) and all the other programs I opened it with were not recognizing it as a link at all. I even tried to add a HyperLink over foo@bar.com with the plan of making it have a white background (hacky, I know), but however I tried to do it has thrown errors. For Link Target I could only choose Self, Top or Parent, yet I would like to make this an actual email link. I have tried a lot of different values for Hyperlink Reference Expression, Hyperlink When Expression and tried also to do this by creating a variable called `mailAddress`, set its expression to be the email address I wanted and then referenced it, by replacing the email address in the quote to mailto:$V{mailAddress}, but it has shown this as a text.

So, my question is: how can I convert part of a static text into a clickable blue email address?

I'm using TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.6.0 - Visual Designer for JasperReports 6.6.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this way:
in the Text property

```
This is a test <u><font color='blue'><a href='https://www.google.it'>Link</a></font></u> inside a static text
```

and set the Markup property to "html"

this is the source:

```
<staticText>
  <reportElement x="0" y="130" width="230" height="41" uuid="01126997-9310-462e-bc3c-afd94a21ce63"/>
  <textElement markup="html"/>
  <text><![CDATA[This is a test <u><font color='blue'><a href='https://www.google.it'>Link</a></font></u> inside a static text]]> 
  </text>
</staticText>
```

Tested with Jaspersoft Studio 6.10.0